# How many ways 5 different books can be distributed among 10 people if each person can get any number of books?

Tags: combinatorics

(Hi first time posting here so apologies if this is not the right way)

I know that the answer to this is $10^5$ but I don't really understand why this is so? Shouldn't the number of books or people be decreasing throughout the calculation? Maybe like 10P5? Or is it because of the fact that they did not distinguish between people that allows us to repeat the $10$?

Have tried looking up online and they only give the calculation.

Also is this a combination type question? Specifically something like number of combinations of $n$ distinct objects i.e. $2^n$

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Is there a better way to phrase this question so that more people can see this question without having to ask a similar question to this?

Comment: To get more sight on this divide e.g. $3$ books among $2$ persons and have a close look on what happens.

Comment: $10P5$ is the answer on the question: "on how many ways can I divide $5$ different books among $10$ persons in such a way that a person will receive at most one book?" $10C5$  is the answer on the question: "on how many ways can I divide $5$ equal books among $10$ persons in such a way that a person will receive at most one book?"

Comment: yes i tried to do it with 3 books 2 people and heres what i came up with just by doing brute force calculation: my first answer was 9 and what i did was setting 2 people up and just noting down how all the combinations (p1 has 0 books, p2 has 0 books and successively incrementing). This means that to get 2^3, we are ignoring the combination where both people dont have any books.  Then i tried to put combinations for the books they could choose i.e. instead of p1 has 1 book, p2 has 1 book; now p1 has 3C1 books and p2 has 2C1 books which gets me 27. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The first book can go to any of the $10$ persons. And then  the next book can also go to any of the $10$ persons, and so on. So there are $(10)^{5}$ possibilities.